# How to parse Json without array name in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, object, url

I am new in Android. I want to create a Periodic Table app. I found the json file and the url on github but the json do not have the array name how can I can get the object. I am following CS50 Android track to code this application but I am using another Json file. The tutorial link https://youtu.be/OJQ8Cse6-Ss
Below is my program code:

```
 public void loadElement()
{
    String url = "https://periodic-table-api.herokuapp.com/";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0;i < arr.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    element.add(new Element(
                            object.getString("name"),
                            object.getString("symbol")
                    ));
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("example", "Json error");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("example", "Element list error");
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

The url of Json file https://periodic-table-api.herokuapp.com
Below is the Json file (Here just first two object):

```
[{
"atomicMass": "1.00794(4)",
"atomicNumber": 1,
"atomicRadius": 37,
"boilingPoint": 20,
"bondingType": "diatomic",
"cpkHexColor": "FFFFFF",
"density": 0.0000899,
"electronAffinity": -73,
"electronegativity": 2.2,
"electronicConfiguration": "1s1",
"groupBlock": "nonmetal",
"ionRadius": "",
"ionizationEnergy": 1312,
"meltingPoint": 14,
"name": "Hydrogen",
"oxidationStates": "-1, 1",
"standardState": "gas",
"symbol": "H",
"vanDelWaalsRadius": 120,
"yearDiscovered": 1766},{
"atomicMass": "4.002602(2)",
"atomicNumber": 2,
"atomicRadius": 32,
"boilingPoint": 4,
"bondingType": "atomic",
"cpkHexColor": "D9FFFF",
"density": 0.0001785,
"electronAffinity": 0,
"electronegativity": "",
"electronicConfiguration": "1s2",
"groupBlock": "noble gas",
"ionRadius": "",
"ionizationEnergy": 2372,
"meltingPoint": "",
"name": "Helium",
"oxidationStates": "",
"standardState": "gas",
"symbol": "He",
"vanDelWaalsRadius": 140,
"yearDiscovered": 1868}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response has a JSONArray as root/top element so the type of the Response.Listener should match it. The elements in a JSONArray do not have names, so they are retrieved using the index as you have already done:

```
public void loadElement() {
    String url = "https://periodic-table-api.herokuapp.com/";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                element.add(new Element(
                        object.getString("name"),
                        object.getString("symbol")
                ));
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("example", "Json error");
        }
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("example", "Element list error");
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```